# Finding co ordinates of selected rectangle in pdf

Tags: java

I am using pdf box for  converting pdf pages to images and adding these images to the jframe .I draw the rectangle in jframe using paint method and got the co ordinates of rectangle.My requirement is using these co ordinates i have to clean up the text in pdf .For that i written below logic but it is not working properly. I think the co ordinates what i selected  are different than the itext rectangle co ordinates.please give a solution.

public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest,
            java.awt.Rectangle selectRect) throws IOException,
            DocumentException {

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    Rectangle page = reader.getBoxSize(1, "media");

    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    List<PdfCleanUpLocation> cleanUpLocations = new ArrayList<PdfCleanUpLocation>();

    float lly = page.getHeight() - selectRect.height;
    float ury = page.getHeight() - selectRect.y;
    System.out.println("new pagesize" + lly + "  " + ury);
    cleanUpLocations.add(new PdfCleanUpLocation(1, new Rectangle(0f, lly,
            page.getWidth(), ury), BaseColor.GRAY));

    PdfCleanUpProcessor cleaner = new PdfCleanUpProcessor(cleanUpLocations,
            stamper);

    cleaner.cleanUp();
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

not much familiar with these objects, however at first glance there seems some problem at line "float ury = page.getHeight() - selectRect.y;" . Do you want to to use 'page.y' instead !!

Comment: no,by calculating lly,ury i am getting wrong results so please tell me how to calculate those .